# Who is marc, the default receiver of root mail in /etc/aliases?

Tags: email, root

Is 'marc' some person in the Linux/Unix community?

In `/etc/aliases` on a default centos install, the bottom line reads:

```
   # Person who should get root's email
   # root:  marc
```

Or is it just a random name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example, but it wasn’t picked out of thin air: `marc` is [Marc Ewing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Ewing), who created Red Hat Linux and wrote the initial version of the `/etc/aliases` file which ends up in CentOS.

The line is commented out, so it doesn’t have any effect; if you want to redirect email sent to root, it’s up to you to choose whatever recipient is appropriate, correct the line to take that into account, and uncomment it.

Comment: I knew it had to be someone associated, just couldn't place it in my answer. Kind of like the Noob Saibot character in Mortal Combat being the last names of Ed Boon and John Tobias, the creators of Mortal Kombat, spelled backwards.

Answer (score 2):

*Correction to the first part of my answer even though another answer has been accepted*:

It's not entirely random but Marc Ewing, the creator or Red Hat and writer of the initial `/etc/aliases` (just providing to give clarity).

If you'll notice, the line is commented out.. If you wanted to set an alias for mail going to `root` then you'd uncomment the line and replace `marc` with other users or email addresses that you want to get mail addressed to `root`.